# Burn ERC1155 from ERC721 Contract

Tags: hardhat, erc-721, testing, erc-1155, mocha

Would like to understand on how burn mechanism works on ERC1155, the ERC1155 is an airdrop token that will be use on GeneratedNFT.sol mint function so that it will to mint an ERC721 token and burn the airdrop token. I have tested the burn function from Airdrop.sol and getting no error but encountered a permission error on ERC721.

Here is the snippet for both contracts:

from Airdrop.sol

```
function claimAirdrop(bytes32[] memory _proof) external {
        if (s_claimed[msg.sender]) {
            revert Airdrop__AlreadyClaimed(msg.sender);
        }
        if (!_verifyProof(_proof)) {
            revert Airdrop__NotInAllowList(msg.sender);
        }

        s_claimed[msg.sender] = true;

        uint256 tokenId = s_tokenCounter;

        s_tokenOwners[tokenId] = msg.sender;
        s_tokenCounter += 1;

        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId, 1, "");
        s_tokenURIs[tokenId] = _generateTokenURI(msg.sender);

        emit AirdropClaimed(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        require(s_claimed[msg.sender], "Airdrop: Token not claimed"); ===> Error stop at here
        return s_tokenOwners[_tokenId];
    }

    function burn(uint256 _tokenId) external {
        require(
            s_tokenOwners[_tokenId] == msg.sender,
            "Airdrop: Caller is not the owner of the airdrop token"
        );

        s_exists[_tokenId] = false;
        _burn(msg.sender, _tokenId, 1);

        emit TokenBurned(msg.sender, _tokenId);
    }

    function getTokenId(address _owner) external view returns (uint256) {
        return s_tokenIds[_own
```

from GeneratedNFT.sol

```
import "./Airdrop.sol";

 Airdrop private airdropInterface;

 constructor(
        address _airdropAddress,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        s_owner = msg.sender;
        airdropInterface = Airdrop(_airdropAddress);
    }

function mint(string memory _tokenURI) public {
        uint256 tokenId = airdropInterface.getTokenId(msg.sender);

        address erc1155Owner = airdropInterface.ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(
            erc1155Owner == msg.sender,
            "GeneratedNFT: Caller does not own airdrop tokens"
        );
        require(
            tokenId != 0,
            "GeneratedNFT: Caller does not have airdrop tokens"
        );
        require(
            !s_isTokenBurned[msg.sender],
            "GeneratedNFT: Airdrop token is already burned"
        );

        airdropInterface.burn(tokenId);
        s_isTokenBurned[msg.sender] = true;

        s_tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = s_tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI);

        emit Mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    }
```

from test script

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    tree = await generateMerkleTree();

    [deployer, minter, user1] = await ethers.getSigners();    

    const airdropFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Airdrop");
    airdrop = await airdropFactory.deploy(root, nftTokenURIs);
    await airdrop.deployed();

    const GeneratedNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("GeneratedNFT");
    generatedNFT = await GeneratedNFT.deploy(airdrop.address, NAME, SYMBOL);
    await generatedNFT.deployed();

    const proof = tree.getHexProof(keccak256(minter.address));
    transaction = await airdrop.connect(minter).claimAirdrop(proof);
    result = await transaction.wait(1);
  });

 describe("GeneratedNFT minting", () => {
    describe("Succes", () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        transaction = await airdrop
          .connect(minter)
          .setApprovalForAll(generatedNFT.address, true);
        result = await transaction.wait(1);

        transaction = await generatedNFT.connect(minter).mint(URL);
        result = await transaction.wait();
      });

      it("returns owner", async () => {
        const result = await generatedNFT.ownerOf("1");
        expect(result).to.be.equal(minter.address);
      });
    });
  });
```

This is the error message that I've got

```
 1) GeneratedNFT
       GeneratedNFT minting
         Succes
           "before each" hook for "returns owner":
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Airdrop: Token not claimed'
      at Airdrop.balanceOf (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol:71)
      at Airdrop.ownerOf (contracts/Airdrop.sol:87)
      at GeneratedNFT.mint (contracts/GeneratedNFT.sol:35)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
      at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
      at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
```

Comment: The error message is not complete. Make sure you copied the error properly

Comment: I have updated with full error as above

Comment: The error is coming from the ownerOf function.`require(s_claimed[msg.sender], "Airdrop: Token not claimed");`